# CloudFormation: What is a RegEx to match S3 bucket names that do not have periods (dots)

Tags: java, regex, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

For a CloudFormation template that allows the end-user to enter the name of an S3 bucket that *does not* include periods (dots), what is a regular expression pattern that can be used in the [*AllowedPattern* attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-regexes.html)?

*(Note: a [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=CloudFormation%3A%20What%20is%20a%20RegEx%20to%20match%20S3%20bucket%20names%20that%20do%20not%20have%20periods%20(dots)) for this question does not return well-matched answers.)*

Comment: Your efforts on answering the question is obvious but on forming the question is not. The requirements and failing attempts should be included in details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern that I created that works for me:

```
(?=^.{3,63}$)(^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\-]+[a-z0-9]+$)
```

Essentially, what this does is:

1. Looks ahead to ensure the length is between 3 and 63 chars (inclusive).
2. Starts with at least 1 lowercase letter or number.
3. Has 1 or more lowercase letters, numbers of hyphens.
4. Ends with at least 1 lowercase letter or number.

And when you enter it into the CloudFormation template, remember to escape the backslash:

```
(?=^.{3,63}$)(^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\\-]+[a-z0-9]+$)
```

You may also use the useful [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SMje4q/1) site to test it and view its components.

Comment: This is equal to `^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]+$`.

Comment: You need to remove the `+` to disallow repeating the starting and ending expressions, like this: `^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$`